# Extracting integral curves from discrete vector field (Mathematica)

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica, field, curve, integral

I am trying to write a Mathematica script that can interpolate a discrete vector field to a continuous vector field.  I then want to extract the integral curves (field lines) from the continuous vector field.

I know that Mathematica's `ListStreamPlot` function can visually present integral curves; however, I need the actual points that comprise them.

I have considered writing a brute-force method to the following effect: It seems that the integral curve could be determined recursively.  If a point were picked in the list, then the "next" point in the integral curve would be that with the closest slope.  (Each "point" is actually a vector, and thus each has its own slope.)  There are only 4 candidates for the "next" point -- up, down, left, or right of the current point.  The "next" point would then become the new starting point, and the process would recurse until the edge of the grid is reached.

However, I wonder if there is a simpler method using Mathematica's higher-level functions.  (I also don't know if my method is even conceptually correct.)

I would really appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Make up some data:

```
data = Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];
```

Build a `ListStreamPlot`

```
plot = ListStreamPlot[data, 
          StreamStyle -> "Line", Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

In Mathematica everything is an **expression** - so even this plot is basically visualized code of graphics primitives. You can extract those primitives - including lines you need - by various ways. For example - just picking parts of expression you cam find all points comprising this plot:

```
points = plot[[1, 2, 1]];
```

If you need to see the whole expression evaluate `plot//InputForm`. Now you could also do pattern matching to see inside expression. lets find all indexes comprising all your lines:

```
indexes = Cases[plot, Line[index_] -> index, Infinity];
```

Now you have everything to analyse, draw and stylize your lines. For example - design an app that highlights a specific line in the original plot:

```
Animate[Show[
  plot,
  Graphics[{Red, Opacity[.5], , Thickness[.02], 
    Line[points[[indexes[[k]]]]]}]]
 , {{k, 1, "lines"}, 1, Length[indexes], 1}, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I realise this is an old topic, but I'm working on this same problem. Do you maybe have any clue as to how this function is implemented in Mathematica? How does it compute the integral curves through this discrete vector field? Thanks